# Automatic Script to turn off and on

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to know how to create a script that Automatically stop and start a Google Compute Engine instance. and how can I configure him to run every day and choose to run it only 5 days a week?

because we are not using the server it nights so i can save 9 hours a day.

can it be done?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) in conjunction with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to run lightweight cronjobs which start/stop GCE VM instances based on a schedule that you control.

You can find a [step-by-step tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/scheduling-instances-with-cloud-scheduler) in the official docs, but the general flow is:

1. Use Cloud Scheduler to publish start/stop messages to a [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) topic at the desired times (ex: every weekday at 9am, write a start VM event, every weekday at 5pm, write a stop VM event)
2. Create a Cloud Function which subscribes to the Pub/Sub topic, and makes the appropriate calls to the GCE APIs to trigger start/stop VM.

Comment: Welcome to [so], and thanks for answering! While this resource may answer the question, [it is necessary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and ideally to provide the link for reference. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future! Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the feedback lucascaro - added some more details to the answer so that it stands alone.

Comment: The provided link no longer shows a step-by-step tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `gcloud` command line tool for that (of course from another machine), it provides all controls, including starting and stopping instances. Setup cron on your local machine for:

```
gcloud compute instances stop INSTANCE_NAMES
gcloud compute instances start INSTANCE_NAMES
```

See more:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/stop
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, GCE doesn't provide scheduled VM stop/start as a managed feature, it has to be triggered outside of the VM. For example, you can a [GAE scheduled task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#cron) which uses gcloud or GCE Python SDK to start and stop your VM.